# Trouble when drawing a 2nd object without texture

Tags: java, opengl, drawing, lwjgl

Im having trouble geting a 2nd box to render.
So fare I have 1 object drawn with a texture and it seems to work fine but I have some code attached to it, so if I hold down the left mouse button ontop of it a 2nd box apears to its right.
Instead the 2nd box fails to apear and the textured box disaperes altogether.

I think im missing something with opengl, like something i have to enable or disable before or after drawing 1 thing.

heres my initilization code for opengl:

```
private static void glInit(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
```

heres the code that draws the objects:

```
public void render(){
    if(myImage != null){            
        myImage.bind();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            // upper left
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            // upper right
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(x + size, y);
            // bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(x + size, y + size);
            // bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x, y + size);
        }
        glEnd();

    }

    if(drawChoiceBox){
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {

            glVertex2f(x + size, y - size);
            glVertex2f(x + size*2, y - size);
            glVertex2f(x + size*2, y + size*2);
            glVertex2f(x + size, y + size*2);
        }
        glEnd();
    }

}
```

I have tested the logic for geting the 2nd box up and its works so i guess it must be me missing somthing with the way opengl draws things.
Any idea what im missing? that is ALL the opengl code in my project right now.

Comment: All od the code you have there this "initialization" function actually belongs into the drawing function. Typical newbie misconception, but as a flat state machine there's little to initialize. Instead you set all the state right before you need it when you need it. You need texuturing for an object → glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_…). You need *no* texturing → glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_…) and same goes for any other state. The only things that make sense putting outside the drawing code is upload of image and geometry data, i.e. textures and buffer objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're disabling texturing for the 2nd object, so it's being drawn with texture.

Meanwhile your first box doesn't have glColor() specified, so after drawing the 2nd box, the first will be red. This could make it disappear, if modulating by red produces black, and modulation is enabled.

So you should probably explicitly enable/disable texturing when drawing your quads, as well as specifying all the vertex attributes which are changed, such as colour.

Comment: ah I see, so i have to enable and disable texturing and glcolor between objects. EDIT: The 2nd box now renders but im not sure how to use glcolor for just 1 object, il google it tho.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, if your code requires them to be particular values, you must set them - GL will otherwise take the last value it was given, it doesn't go back to some default state after drawing. (you probably just want to set the colour to white before your first object - `glColor3f(1,1,1);`)